# python version change after importing environment yml file

Tags: python, yaml, conda

My colleague shared their environment yml file with me and the python version of the env is 3.8.5. However, after I import their yml file and create an env the python version is changed to 3.8.13 when I run "python --version". Does anyone know what causes the issue and how to ensure the python version remain the same after import? Thank you.

Here is my code:

to create an env

```
conda env create -f myenv.yml
```

then activate it

```
conda activate myenv
```

to check the python version in the env

```
python --version
```

please see below for part of the ymal file.

```
name: myenv

channels: defaults

dependencies:
  - ca-certificates=2022.07.19=haa95532_0
  - certifi=2022.6.15=py38haa95532_0
  - openssl=1.1.1q=h2bbff1b_0
  - pip=22.1.2=py38haa95532_0
  - python=3.8.5=h5fd99cc_1
  - setuptools=61.2.0=py38haa95532_0
  - sqlite=3.39.2=h2bbff1b_0
  - vc=14.2=h21ff451_1
  - vs2015_runtime=14.27.29016=h5e58377_2
  - wheel=0.37.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0
  - wincertstore=0.2=py38haa95532_2
  - pip:
    - argon2-cffi==21.3.0
    - argon2-cffi-bindings==21.2.0
    - asttokens==2.0.5
    - attrs==22.1.0
   ......... 
   (more pip packages)
```

Comment: Have you seen this?: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file . Specifically, the 2nd step, activating the environment.

Comment: Hi, yes I have activated the environment. I followed the documentation to import the yml too, and receive the error above.

Comment: Can you share the yaml file? Or at least the section which declares required python.

Comment: sure! i have edited my post to include it. I was wondering it has something to do with channels. Thanks.

Comment: What you describe is not possible - it must be a misinterpretation. Please add the following to the question body: 1) the exact commands to create the environment (`conda env create ...`); 2) how you activate the environment 3) how you verify the environment is activated 4) how you check the Python version. Rather than say "I run `python --version` and find ...", instead, show us the shell where you type this in and the exact output.

Comment: After uninstall python 3.10 and install 3.9 the issue is resolved.